# GIT's ls-remote test switch always returning false

Tags: git, bash

For some reason my bash switch below will always return false/or, I was looking for a way to suppress the response from git which will as for a User/Pass sequence when the repository doesn't exist, but could not get this working?

```
[ git ls-remote https://github.com/ehime/Bash-Tools.git &>- /dev/null ] && { 
    echo Exists 
} || { 
    echo Nope 
}
```

I tried this and it does work, but will not supress content like I wanted

```
[ "$(git ls-remote foo)" ] && { echo Yes; } || { echo No; }
```

Comment: You aren't running git in that test you are giving test a series of strings (which is almost certainly causing `[` to output an error message).

Comment: I was origionall using `[ "$(git ls-remote https://github.com/ehime/Bash-Tools.git &>- /dev/null)" ] && { echo Yes; } || { echo No; }`

Comment: That will correctly run the git command but since you are attempting to discard all output that isn't going to do what you want either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't running git in that test you are giving test a series of strings (which is almost certainly causing `[` to output an error message).

If you are trying to run that command ignoring all output and test only the return code you want to drop the bracketing `[` and `]`. They aren't part of the `if` syntax. `[` is a binary (synonymous with `test`).

`if git ls-remote ...; then` will run git and test its return code.

Additionally, the `/dev/null` there is not doing anything for you. `$>-` is closing standard input and standard output already. `/dev/null` there is the "ref" argument to `git ls-remote`.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was

```
[ "$(git ls-remote $REPOSITORY_URL 2> /dev/null)" ] && { echo Exists; } || { echo Nope; }
```

Full git command for a restricted git shell if anyone wants it

```
# If no project name is given
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    # Display usage and stop
    echo "Usage: addrepo <project.git>" ; exit 1
fi

# Set the project name, adding .git if necessary
project=$(echo "$*" | sed 's/\.git$\|$/.git/i')

[ "$(git ls-remote $project 2> /dev/null)" ] && {
    cd /home/git/repositories/
    git clone --mirror "${project}"
} || {
    echo "[ERROR] Unable to read from '${project}'"; exit 1
}
```

Comment: You probably actually do want to test the return code and not the output. Which is why `--exit-code` exists but yes, this will work assuming that `ls-remote` only has output when some refs are found (assuming that's the test you want).

Comment: Unfortunately exit code usually return bool false when it successfully communicates with a repo, so will also always fail the statement. IMHO trying to mirror an empty repository is pointless.

Comment: Ah, true, the documentation for `--exit-code` certainly does seem to indicate that the return code is not as useful as it might be.